# Как вы верстаете формы(GUI)?

Tags: java, swing

[image: пример формы]
Получается я для начала собирал линию 1, 2, 3... потом собирал эти линии в форму(как на рис.). Пользуюсь GridBagConstraints.
Теперь при добавлении новых полей для ввода и т.п.(обведено синим) элементы формы начинают "ехать", а если поле большое по высоте то и сдвигает все нижние линии.
Не знаю как формулировать вопрос... короче, как можно сделать красиво?

Comment: Можно совмещать разные (и одинаковые) лайоуты, помещая один в другой. Экспериментируйте. Не рисовать же за вас.

Comment: Значит, грубо говоря, экспериментировать пока не придет просветление?)

Comment: Можете поискать литературу по свинг, где хорошо описываются менеджеры расположения. Чтобы без лишних экспериментов знать чего от них ожидать. Кроме компонентов ввода есть всякие распорки и пружины. Могут пригодиться чтобы оттолкнуть или приблизить элементы друг к другу